# set nospell in .vimrc has no effect

Tags: vim

I am trying to disable spellcheck in vim.

I have tried adding `set nospell` to my *.vimrc* but that has no effect. If I type `:set nospell` while editing a file it works - but I want to disable it globally. Any suggestions?

Comment: Start vim and then do `:verbose set spell?`. That will tell you where the option was last set.

Comment: Thanks! I removed a few things that were not supposed to be in my .vimrc and it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

If you follow [`:help 'spell'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27spell%27), you'll see that this option is *local to window*. If you use `:set` during Vim startup (e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`), you'll set the global default and the first window's option, but this doesn't mean that *filetype plugins* or other `:autocmd` cannot change the option again later.

Vim can usually tell you who set an option last, via

```
:verbose set spell?
```

This often gives you a hint how to undo or prevent an undesired configuration change. Plugins usually have configuration, and filetype plugins can be overridden via the [`after-directory`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#after-directory).